# jQuery AJAX size always the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, xmlhttprequest

I'm sending data through `AJAX` requests to a `PHP` server (cross-domain).

I am currently trying to reduce the request size. The problem is that, in the Chrome Network panel the size of the request is always the same: **377 bytes** even if the `Content-Length` is 800 or 0.

Here are the headers sent by **$.ajax**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,id;q=0.4,nl;q=0.2,pt;q=0.2,ro;q=0.2,it;q=0.2,ja;q=0.2
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:776
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36
```

What is the minimum request size? Why adding extra data does not increase the request size? (the data is sent through POST as form data).

What's even stranger is tht when I do another request which has similar headers and much less form data, that request takes **2.5KB**. The **377b** request is done every few seconds, does the browser optimize the next requests? Why is a request with fewer data larger than a request with more form data?

Tested in **Google Chrome**

Here's how  the data looks, even though I send at least 400-500B of form-data.
[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you exactly mean by "request size". `Content-Length` header or something else?

Comment: @hindmost It's what Google Chrome shows under the `size` column of the network tab. See the attached picture.

Comment: On Firefox it shows the right content-length. I start to think it's a problem with Chrome network stats, not with the AJAX request size itself.

Comment: Also, one more thing: I think the size is the size of the **response** not of the **request**. Still, the content-length is always 0?

Comment: Yeah, my bad: the Content-Length and size are for **inbound data**, anyone know how can I see the size of the data sent in Chrome? Firefox shows the correct size under the "transferred" column.

Comment: It's been over six years, but unfortunately chrome devtools still show only the response size, and the only option remains to use Proxyman (Mac), Fiddler (Windows) or other debugging proxies